# Passport Profile not passing new properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I'm using Passport OAuth2.0 with Google as my provider, and having a weird syntax problem.

My authentication looks like this:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {
    User.findOrCreate({id:profile.id}, function(err, user, created){
        if(err){return err;}
        else if(!created){
          console.log("Found User");

          user.lastSeen = new Date();
          user.save();

          var u=profile;
          u.lastSeen = user.lastSeen;
          return done(null, u);
        }
        else{
          console.log("Created User");
          User.create({id:profile.id, lastSeen: new Date()});
          user.save();
          var u=profile;
          u.lastSeen = new Date();
          return done(null, u);

        }

      });
      return done(null, profile);
    });
  }
));
```

For some reason, when I pass `u` back to jade, it doesn't seem to have a `.lastSeen` property, and neither does my database.

The right functions are getting called (i.e. if I clear my db, I get "Created User" in my console, otherwise I get "Found User"), and the user object is coming through with the `._json` property into my jade template, and displaying the profile pic, but I can't seem to get my custom stuff to stick, or at least break something and throw an error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Whoops.

`.findOrCreate()` was being called asynchronously, so `ls` didn't exist in it's context. To fix the problem all I had to do was:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {

      User.findOrCreate({id:profile.id},{lastSeen:new Date()}, function(err, user, created){
        var ls;
        if(err){return err;}
        else{ 

          if(!created){
            console.log("Found User");
            var u = user.lastSeen;
            user.lastSeen = new Date();
            user.save(function(err){
              err?console.log(err):null;
            });
            ls=u;

          }
          else{
            console.log("Created User");
            ls="New User";
          }
        }
        console.log("ls = "+ls);
        console.log(typeof profile);
        profile.lastSeen = ls;
        console.log(profile.lastSeen);

        return done(null, profile);

      });        
    });
  }
));
```

Well, that's embarrassing. Hope this saves someone else the trouble.